# Haskell and General Types

Tags: function, haskell, generics, lambda, types

I'm kind of new to *Haskell*, and I would like to understand how general types works.

What should be a "systematic" way of thinking to get the type of an expression?

To make an example, if we have:

```
(\x y z -> x (y z))
```

The way I would think about this, would just be to use intuition, but it doesn't work always.

In this case I would say:

```
   (y z) :: (t -> t1) --function y takes t and return t1
 x (y z) :: (t1 -> t2) --function x takes argument of type (return type of y)

(\x y z -> x (y z)) :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t -> t1) -> t -> t2 --return type is t2 (of x) with argument of type t for function y
```

I'm pretty sure this should be right, but sometimes it's harder and this way go thinking doesn't seems to work.

For example if we have:

```
1.  (\x -> x (<))  or
2.  (.) . (.)
```

In this cases I would have no idea how to find the types, for the first I would guess that (<) is a function on two elements that returns a `Bool` but I have troubles writing the hole expression.

So the question is, what is the best way work with this kind of exercises?

---

ADDED: I know how to check the types with `ghci`, the question was how to actually find them without it (to understand how Haskell works).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily check the type of an expression with `:t` in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :t (\x y z -> x (y z))
(\x y z -> x (y z)) :: (r1 -> r) -> (r2 -> r1) -> r2 -> r
Prelude> :t (\x -> x (<))
(\x -> x (<)) :: Ord a => ((a -> a -> Bool) -> r) -> r
Prelude> :t (.) . (.)
(.) . (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c
```

But I assume you want to derive the types yourself.

1. For the first we can start with looking to the variables. Those are `x`, `y` and `z`. We first assign "generic types" to them, so:

   ```
   x :: a
   y :: b
   z :: c
   ```

   Now we look to the right hand of the expression and see `(y z)`. This means that we "call" `y` with `z` as argument. As a result we "specialize" the type of `y` to `y :: c -> d`. The type of `(y z)` then is `(y z) :: d`. Now we see that `x (y z)`. So again we "specialize" the type of `x` into `x :: d -> e`. As a result we obtain:

   ```
   x :: d -> e
   y :: c -> d
   z :: c
   ```

   Finally the lambda-expression maps `\x y z -> x (y z)`. So that means we look to the resulting type is something in "pseudo code": `type(x) -> type(y) -> type(z) -> type('x (y z)')`. Or:

   ```
   \x y z -> x (y z) :: (d -> e) -> (c -> d) -> c -> e
   ```
2. For the second expression we first have to derive the type of `(<)`:

   ```
   Prelude> :t (<)
   (<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
   ```

   This is because `(<)` is somewhere defined in the `Prelude` with that type.

   Now we know that, we can look at the type signature. We will first assume a type for `x :: b`. Now we look to the right side, and see that we call `x (<)`. So that means we know `x` has the type `Ord a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> c` and we know that `x (<) :: c`. Then again we have a lambda-expression, and as we have seen above, we can resolve it like:

   ```
   (\x -> x (<)) :: Ord a => ((a -> a -> Bool) -> c) -> c
   ```
3. Finally for the third expression, let is first rewrite it to:

   ```
   (.) (.) (.)
   ```

   Here the *first* `(.)` function, was originally the `.` (without brackets), but we will first remove the operator syntactical sugar.

   Next we will give the operators a name (only to make it more convenient for us to name them). This is *not* allowed in Haskell, but we will ignore that for now. The reason we do this is to later refer to the type of a specific `(.)` function:

   ```
   (.1) (.2) (.3)
   ```

   Next we lookup the type for `(.)`:

   ```
   Prelude> :t (.)
   (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
   ```

   So we first assign some types:

   ```
   (.1) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
   (.2) :: (e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
   (.3) :: (h -> i) -> (g -> h) -> g -> i
   ```

   Now we need to analyze these types further. We call `(.1)` with `(.2)` as argument so we know that `(b -> c)` (the first argument of `(.1)` is equivalent to `(e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f`. So that means that:

   ```
   (b -> c) ~ (e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f
   ```

   Since the type arrows are *right associative*, `(e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f` actually means `(e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`. So now we can make an analysis:

   ```
     b        -> c
   ~ (e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
   ```

   So that means `b ~ (e -> f)` and `c ~ ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`. So we "specialize" our first `(.1) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` into

   ```
   (.1) :: ((e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))) -> (a -> (e -> f)) -> a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
   ```

   Now the type of `(.1) (.2)` is

   ```
   (.1) (.2) :: (a -> (e -> f)) -> a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
   ```

   But now we call that function with `(.3)` so we have to derive the type for `((.1) (.2)) (.3)`. Therefore again we have to do type resolution with:

   ```
     a        -> (e        -> f)
   ~ (h -> i) -> ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))
   ```

   So that means `a ~ (h -> i)`, `e ~ (g -> h)` and `f ~ (g -> i)`. So now we have resolved the type to:

   ```
   ((.1) (.2)) (.3) :: a -> c
   =                   (h -> i) -> ((d -> (g -> h)) -> (d -> (g -> i)))
   =                   (h -> i) -> (d -> g -> h) -> d -> g -> i
   ```

   The last line is only a syntactical simplification. As you can see, this maps on the type we derived from `ghci`.

As you can see for all three queries we obtain the same type (of course the name of the type variables is different).

Comment: Very interesting approach, how would you do it with `(\x -> x (<))`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to understand. Could you show me how you would do it with `(.).(.)`, since in this case we don't have any lambda expression..

Answer (score 3):

Using the GHC compiler, you can ask about type by using type holes, `_`

for instance:

```
thing :: _
thing = (\x -> (<))
```

yields:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: t -> a0 -> a0 -> Bool
Where: ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of thing :: t -> a0 -> a0 -> Bool
           at src/Expat/Data/E.hs:555:1
       ‘a0’ is an ambiguous type variable
To use the inferred type, enable PartialTypeSignatures
In the type signature for ‘thing’: _
```

I sometimes use this with where clauses to isolate expressions in larger functions, e.g.

```
myFun :: a -> b
myFun a = otherFun thing
  where 
    thing :: _
    thing = (\x -> (<))
```

You can also use holes in place of terms. For instance, if I'm not sure exactly what otherFun should be, I could just substitute in `_`.